# Is location-dependent convolution filter possible in PyTorch or TensorFlow?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network, convolution

Let's pretend that in plus of having an image, I also have a gradient from left to right on the X axis of an image, and another gradient from top to bottom on the Y axis. Those two gradients are of the same size of the image, and could both range from -0.5 to 0.5.

Now, I'd like to make the convolution kernel (a.k.a. convolution filter, or convolution weights) depend on the `(x, y)` location in the gradient. So the kernel is a function of the gradient as if the kernel was the output of a nested mini-neural net. This would make the weights of the filter to be different in every position, but slightly similar to their neighbors. How do I do that within PyTorch or TensorFlow?

Sure, I could compute a [Toeplitz matrix (a.k.a. diagonal-constant matrix)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix#Discrete_convolution)  by myself, but the matrix multiplication would take `O(n^3)` operations if pretending `x==y==n`, whereas convolutions can be implemented in `O(n^2) normally`. Or I could maybe iterate on every element myself and do the multiplications in an unvectorized fashion.

Any better ideas? I'd like to see creativity here, thinking about how could this be implemented neatly. I believe coding that would be an interesting way to build a network layer capable of doing things similar to a simplified version of a [Spatial Transformer Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02025), but which's spatial transformation would be independent of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution I thought for a simplified version of this problem where a linear combination of weights would be used rather than truly using a nested mini neural network:

It may be possible to do 4 different convolutions passes so as to have 4 feature maps, then to multiply those 4 maps with the gradients (2 vertical and 2 horizontal gradients), and add them together so that only 1 map remains. However, that would be a linear combination of the different maps which is simpler than truly using a nested neural network which would alter the kernel in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking more about it, here is a solution to an equivalent question. The thing with this solution is that it flips the problem around by placing the "mini neural net" after rather than before, and in a quite different way. So it solves the problem, but offer a much different optimization space and convergence behavior which is less natural for me to think about than how I formulated the problem.

In a sense, a solution to the problem could be very similar to simply concatenating the two gradients to 1 regular feature map (from a regular convolution) such as having a depth of `d_2 = d_1 + 2` after the concatenation), and then performing more convolutions on top of this. I won't prove why this is a valid solution to an equivalent problem, but I thought through this and it seems provable.

The optimization space (for the weights) would be here very different and I think it wouldn't converge with the same behavior. I'd like to know what you people think about this solution in terms of optimization convergence.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why convolutions are more efficient than fully connected layers is **because** they are translation invariant. If you wish to have convolutions which are dependent on location you would need to add two extra parameters to the convolution i.e. having N+2 input channels where x, y coord are the values of the two additonal channels (as in e.g. [CoordConv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.03247)).

As for alternative solutions, is the gradient meaningful? If not, and it is uniform across all images, it might be better to just manually remove it in the pre-processing stage (similar to orientation correction, cropping etc). If it is not (e.g. differences in lighting, shadows) then including other layers under the assumption they would learn the invariance of different lightings is a common hands-off approach.